# Javascript Geolocation to within 10 meters

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

```
window.onload = function() {
  var startPos;
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  startPos = position;
  document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;

  var a =  { lat: 40.6, lng: -70.4 }

  var b = { lat: startPos.coords.latitude, lon: startPos.coords.longitude }


  zone = haversineDistance(a,b);
  document.getElementById('zone').innerHTML = zone;

  if(zone < 50){
    document.getElementById('inout').innerHTML = 'IN';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('inout').innerHTML = 'OUT';
  }

});
};

var atan2 = Math.atan2
var cos = Math.cos
var sin = Math.sin
var sqrt = Math.sqrt
var PI = Math.PI

// (mean) radius of Earth (meters)
var R = 6378137

function squared (x) { return x * x }
function toRad (x) { return x * PI / 180.0 }

function haversineDistance (a, b) {
var aLat = a.latitude || a.lat
var bLat = b.latitude || b.lat
var aLng = a.longitude || a.lng || a.lon
var bLng = b.longitude || b.lng || b.lon

var dLat = toRad(bLat - aLat)
var dLon = toRad(bLng - aLng)

var f = squared(sin(dLat / 2.0)) + cos(toRad(aLat)) * cos(toRad(bLat)) * squared(sin(dLon / 2.0))
var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(f), sqrt(1 - f))

return R * c
}
```

I found this code online and it works well I just wanted to be able to add multiple locations to the object and when within 10 meters of a location alert. Not really sure how to get started any help would be great,

Answer (score 0):

This is no answer you can take and have your problem solved, but I will guide you in the right direction and I'm sure you can solve this.

#### Your problem:

So first of all as you already mentioned this code is a very good foundation to start.
You described two goals:

1. Have multiple locations
2. Alert if they are 10 meters or less to each
       other

#### Solve one after each other

1. Problem: You should probably use an `array` to store your multiple locations.
   This could look something like this:
   `var locations = [ {lat: 12.314, long: 0.125}, {lat: 12.314, long: 0.125} ]`
   To learn more about arrays and the fundamental JavaScript I suggest to look [here](https://javascript.info/first-steps)
2. Problem:
   You already have the complicated part for this solved. You can just use the 
   `function haversineDistance`
   to calculate the distance between two locations. So everything you have to do here is just compare each new location you get with all currently existing locations and use something like `alert()` to make your alert.
   I would suggest to use maybe [swal](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) if you like to but this is not related just my flavour and I have nothing to do with this project.

But nothing is as good as playing around get to know that language and to learn.

Comment: perfect, I didn't want the answer just some suggestions in the right direction. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I would appreciate it if you would accept this answer :)